# How to solve the Boundary value problem using finite difference method

Tags: boundary-value-problem, finite-differences

I am solving Boundary value problem using finite difference method from a reference book, but one of the step is not quite clear to me - for more clear view I am sharing a screen shot of that question below.

Can anyone help me how that step comes? I had shown that step with the red marker. Please explain me how that step comes?

**[Question Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q96sR.png)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line you marked is:
$$16y_{i+1} - 33y_i + 16y_{i-1} = x_i, \quad i = 1,2,3.
$$
It comes from the previous line by substituting 
$$h=1/4, \ \ \ {1\over h^2}=16$$
and then subtracting $y_i$ from both sides of the equation.

Comment: I think I am so dumb! I was taking i/h^2 = 1/16 all the time. Well thank you so much !!